# Django Send Email Does Not Show Any Error

Tags: python, django, email

I am making a parking system with the option Paid and Not Paid, and only when chosen form paid, I want the system to send an email with the payment confirmation.
I am able to send the email via console, but via the system will not and does not present any error

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
import math

PAGO_CHOICES = (
('Não', 'Não Pago'),
('Sim', 'Pago')
)

class MovRotativo(models.Model):
    checkin = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, blank=False, null=False,)
    checkout = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
valor_hora = models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
veiculo = models.ForeignKey(
    Veiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
pago = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PAGO_CHOICES)

def horas_total(self):
    if self.checkout is None:
        return self.checkout == 0
    else:
        return math.ceil((self.checkout - self.checkin).total_seconds() / 3600)

def total(self):
    return self.valor_hora * self.horas_total()

def __str__(self):
    return self.veiculo.placa

def send_email(self):
    if self.pago == 'Sim':
        send_mail(
            'Comprovante pagamento estacionamento',
            'Here is the message.',
            'estacioneaqui24@gmail.com',
            ['estacioneaqui24@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

Comment: What email backend are you using? And when you say you can send an email via the console, do you mean you can print it to the console?

Comment: Where do you call the `send_email` function?

Comment: You do `self.pago is 'Sim'`. Don't compare values with `is`! `is` doesn't test values but object identity. Use `self.pago == 'Sim'` instead.

Comment: Matthias, thnaks man, i try, but dont work too

Comment: Are you sure that function is called and if it's called does `self.pago` have the value you expect? Maybe you should put a `print(self.pago)` as the first line in this function to check that. Even better: have a look at `type(self.pago)` and `repr(self.pago)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a signal or an override to the `save()` method. I will provide you with a signal example. I left some print statements so you could get a better idea.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=MovRotativo)
def before_movrotativo_save(sender, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    if instance.pago == 'Sim':
       print('Send email')
       instance.send_email()
```

Here is my example on how to test it from `shell`:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from application.models import MovRotativo
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> c = MovRotativo.objects.create(valor_hora=2, checkin=timezone.now())
>>> c.pago = 'Sim'
>>> c.save()
```